# N or more continuous year range

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have to create a report using MySql DB where more than 4 tables are involved. I have one table (S1) with S1_ID and S1_Year_Range (strings like 2001-2002) and another table (S2) with S2_ID(PK), S2_Customer_ID, S1_ID (FK) and other fields for other conditions that can appear in Where clause of my query. There can be more than one row in S2 with the same S2_Customer_ID but different S1_ID. My query is to create a report using VB.net and ask users to enter two values; one number for how many continuous years or bigger (like >= 5 years), and a year range value (like 2011-2012) which is the highest value in the list for all customers.

My report lists customer names (by joining the above query with another table), customer rank and all year range values (highest at the bottom) for that customer in one column for each customer. Any help for this query would be appreciated.

Data and results could be like the following:

S1:

(S1_ID....S1_Year_Range)

(1......2000-2001)

(2......2001-2002)

(3......2002-2003)

(4......2003-2004)

(5......2004-2005)

etc

S2:

(S2_ID.....S2_Customer_ID.....S1_ID)

(1....1....1)

(2....1....2)

(3....1....3)

(4....2....2)

(5....2....3)

(6....2....5)

(7....3....2)

(8....3....3)

(9....3....4)

(10...3....5)

(11...4....3)

(12...4....4)

(13...4....5)

etc

when number 2 and year range (2003-2004) is entered by the user, the result should be the following:

customer 3 with 3 year range values (2003-2004, 2002-2003, and 2001-2002) and customer 4 with 2 year range values (2003-2004 and 2002-2003):

cname3 
 
2001-2002 
2002-2003 
2003-2004 

 
cname4 
 
2002-2003 
 
2003-2004

I hope you can see the columns of the report correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a complex query to solve my problem. In the following query, I encoded the user year range value as '2010-2011' and number of continuous years as 14. Also a tiny difference with the question is the table names; table CSP here is the same as table S2 in my question but field names are the same as those in my question.

SELECT CSYWFY.S2_Customer_ID,  COUNT(CSYWFY.S2_Customer_ID)
FROM (SELECT   S1F.S1_Year_Range, S2.S2_Customer_ID ,  COUNT(S1F.S1_Year_Range) FROM CSP as S2 INNER JOIN  S1 as S1F  ON S2.S1_ID = S1F.S1_ID WHERE  '2010-2011' IN (SELECT S1N.S1_Year_Range FROM CSP as S2N INNER JOIN S1 as S1N ON S2N.S1_ID = S1N.S1_ID WHERE  S2N.S2_Customer_ID = S2.S2_Customer_ID )  GROUP BY   S2.S2_Customer_ID ASC , S1F.S1_Year_Range DESC ) CSYWFY
GROUP BY CSYWFY.S2_Customer_ID 
HAVING COUNT(CSYWFY.S2_Customer_ID) > 14

HTH